# How to perform preload on top of a preload in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

I have these model associations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many taken_tests
.
.
.
end

class Test < ApplicationRecord
   has_many questions
.
.
end
```

Now `User.preload(:taken_tests)` preloads the tests.
Is there a way I can preload questions also along with the tests?
Something like:
`User.preload(:taken_tests).preload(:questions)` ?

Comment: Okay, there is one thing which I did that worked. I added another association to user: `has_many answered_questions, through: :taken_tests, source: questions`. 
Then when I did `User.preload(:answered_questions)`, it preloaded the tests as well as the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can `preload` the chain of associations

```
User.preload(taken_tests: :questions)
```

This will load all the user's tests along with all the questions which belongs to those tests

You can chain the associations if you need if you have answers you can preload them too.

```
User.preload(taken_tests: [questions: :answers])
```